# InvalidParameterValueException: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I'm using the [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) and it is returning the following error when I try to create a Lambda function:

> InvalidParameterValueException: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.

I've double-checked my role and it is perfectly valid. However, I'm still unable to create the Lambda function.

My role trust relationship is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've posted this self-answered question since I've spent a very long time to find the problem. I hope that it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error happens when the role is invalid (which is not the case) or when you try to create the Lambda function **just after** the role creation. Amazon needs a few seconds to replicate your new role through all regions. So, the fix here is to **wait a few seconds before creating the Lambda function**.

## Solution - Example 1:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

var params = {}; // define your parameters

lambda.createFunction(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err && err.code === 'InvalidParameterValueException') {

        // try again after a few seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
            lambda.createFunction(params, callback);
        }, 10000);
    } else {
        callback(err, data);
    }
});
```

## Solution - Example 2:

Usually, waiting 5 seconds is enough, but it can also take a little more. For a more robust solution, you can use a retry module like [this](https://github.com/tim-kos/node-retry) one.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var retry = require('retry');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

var params = {}; // define your parameters

var operation = retry.operation({
    retries: 3,           // try 1 time and retry 3 times if needed, total = 4
    minTimeout: 1 * 1000, // the number of milliseconds before starting the first retry
    maxTimeout: 15 * 1000 // the maximum number of milliseconds between two retries
});

operation.attempt(function(currentAttempt) {
    lambda.createFunction(params, function(err, data) {
        if (operation.retry(err) && err.code === 'InvalidParameterValueException')
            return;

        callback(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing your solution. I had this same problem too. I've tried sleeping myself but the amount of times varied. The second solution looks robust. I hope IAM had a status code to indicate that the role is not ready to be consumed yet :(