# AWS CLI: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, serverless-architecture

AWS CLI version:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.21 Python/2.7.12 Darwin/15.3.0 botocore/1.4.78
```

Trying to create a Lambda function and getting the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda.
```

Role was created as:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name microrole --assume-role-policy-document file://./trust.json
```

`trust.json` is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Policy was attached as:

```
aws iam put-role-policy --policy-document file://./policy.json --role-name microrole --policy-name micropolicy
```

`policy.json` is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "apigateway:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Waited for multiple minutes as mentioned at [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503075/invalidparametervalueexception-the-role-defined-for-the-function-cannot-be-assu) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419442/the-role-defined-for-the-function-cannot-be-assumed-by-lambda) but still the error is not going away. The policy and trust attached to the role is similar to the default role created when Lambda Function is created using Console.

Complete steps are listed at https://github.com/arun-gupta/serverless/tree/master/aws/microservice.

What's missing?

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda function was created as:

```
aws lambda create-function \
--function-name MicroserviceGetAll \
--role arn:aws:iam::<act-id>:role/service-role/microRole \
--handler org.sample.serverless.aws.couchbase.BucketGetAll \
--zip-file fileb:///Users/arungupta/workspaces/serverless/aws/microservice/microservice-http-endpoint/target/microservice-http-endpoint-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
--description "Microservice HTTP Endpoint - Get All" \
--runtime java8 \
--region us-west-1 \
--timeout 30 \
--memory-size 1024 \
--environment Variables={COUCHBASE_HOST=ec2-35-165-83-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com} \
--publish
```

The correct command is:

```
aws lambda create-function \
--function-name MicroserviceGetAll \
--role arn:aws:iam::<act-id>:role/microRole \
--handler org.sample.serverless.aws.couchbase.BucketGetAll \
--zip-file fileb:///Users/arungupta/workspaces/serverless/aws/microservice/microservice-http-endpoint/target/microservice-http-endpoint-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
--description "Microservice HTTP Endpoint - Get All" \
--runtime java8 \
--region us-west-1 \
--timeout 30 \
--memory-size 1024 \
--environment Variables={COUCHBASE_HOST=ec2-35-165-83-82.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com} \
--publish
```

The difference is that the role was incorrectly specified as `role/service-role/microRole` instead of `role/microRole`.